# Android ImageSwitcher with vertical scroll

Tags: android, imageswitcher

I try to change the art of scrolling from a ImageSwitcher.
The normal ImageSwitcher scroll from left to right or right to left.
But I want to scroll from top to bottom or bottom to top.
I din´t find a solution for this problem.
Can anybody help me.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Learn about gesture detection, and based on the fling action, try to produce a animation in the direction you would want and use a flipper to switch the images.

Comment: Try to check my answer. I've came across this issue and solved it using those animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find slide_in_up and slide_out_down in the SDK, see XML files in the platforms/[version]/data/res/anim directory.

It should be simple to look at these and use them to make slide_in_down and slide_out_up if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old question, but... I've solved this issue this way:

Place those two files on your `anim` folder.

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Then, on your `Activity` or `Fragment`, try to do the following:

```
Animation in_rl = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(rootView.getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_right);

Animation out_rl = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(rootView.getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_left);

mImageSwitcher.setInAnimation(in_rl);
mImageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out_rl);
```